# Cramer's V for test of homogeneity

Tags: chi-squared-test, cramers-v

Can Cramer's V be adapted for the chi-squared test of homogeneity?

I know that Cramer's V has been adapted for the chi-squared test of goodness-of-fit, where it indicates the degree of deviation of the observed counts from expected probabilities. See [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/rcompanion/man/cramerVFit.html).

I'm looking for a similar adaptation of Cramer's V that is able to tell us about the degree of the differences detected in the populations. Is there such a measure already implemented? Would really appreciate suggestions here.

Comment: Cramer's V is not a separate test, it is a coefficient of association, one of possible versions of standardized chi-square statistic. The p-value of V is the same as of its corresponding chi-square.

Comment: @ttnphns Much thanks for your clarification. I realize that Cramer's V is merely a measure of association, used for measuring the strength of an association. However, it is most commonly used in tandem with the Chi-squared test of independence. It's value when used in tandem with the Chi-squared test of homogeneity, however, is unclear to me. I'm wondering if there's a modified version of Cramer's V that might be able to indicate the magnitude of the differences detected in the population (not the significance), much like the standard Cramer's V tells us about the strength of an association.

Comment: In what way does the test of homogeneity differ from the test of independence?\* Independence implies homogeneity and vice-versa. Wouldn't the usual Cramer's V measure the same thing either way? ... .... \* See http://math.oxford.emory.edu/site/math117/independenceTest/  or http://srjcstaff.santarosa.edu/~ylin/Math15/notes/Test_of_Independence.htm

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for the excellent references. So if the results of the Chi-squared test of independence and homogeneity are equivalent (i.e., one implies the other), then how do I interpret Cramer's V in the context of the test of homogeneity?

Comment: @Glen_b To follow up my comment above, does a larger Cramer's V (which implies a stronger association) also implies a stronger degree of differences detected between the two populations?